# Magento2 display swatch options on left & right on details page based on category

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

Magento2 How can I display color swatches on left side under image on product details page for 1 category & size swatch on right size under name for another category product details page

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show me image.

Comment: I added images for more clarity